# Export variable from js file to html in static folder (nuxt.js)

Tags: javascript, html, export, nuxt.js, token

I had a problem when I want to import a variable from separated js file to my html code in static folder (nuxt.js). So in pages/index.vue, i have a code to call static/coba folder like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div>

      <!-- Leaflet map -->
      <div ref="map" id="map" class="map h-screen w-screen z-0"></div>
      <div v-if="map">

        <!-- Take list of plugins in static folder -->
        <div v-for="(data, i) in listPlugins" :key="i">
          <component :is="data.name" />
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {

      // Customize map in leaflet
      input: "ea",
      url: null,
      map: null,
      opt: {
        zoomControl: false,
        minZoom: 2,
        zoom: 2,
        center: [0, 115],
        zoomSnap: 0.1,
        scrollWheelZoom: false,
        smoothWheelZoom: true,
        smoothSensitivity: 1.9,
        preferCanvas: true,
      },

      // list plugins in static folder
      listPlugins: [
        {
          name: "signature",
          path: "/coba/"
        }
      ],

    };
  },

  mounted() {
    // import from server side, vue and axios
    this.listPlugins.forEach((el) => {

      // import component
      Vue.component(el.name, function (resolve, reject) {

        // import html
        axios.get(el.path).then((response) => {

          // return template
          resolve({
            template: response.data,
          });

        });
      });
    });

    // import in client side
    this.map = L.map(this.$refs.map, this.opt);
    window.globalMap = this.map;
    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(
      this.map
    );
  },

  computed: {
    compiledHtml: function () {
      return this.input;
    },
  },

};
</script>
```

From that code, i'm successfully to import static/coba/index.html (plugins in static folder). Here's the static/coba/index.html code:

```
<div class="bg-white" id="indexing">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/coba/main.js">
        
    </script>
<script type="application/javascript">console.log(kosJson)</script>
</div>
```

So I want to import 'kosJson' variable from static/coba/main.js file to static/coba/index.html file. Here's the static/coba/main.js code:

```
var kosJson = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    bbox: [110.340501, -7.791898, 110.397112, -7.725499],
    features: [
      {
        type: "Feature",
        properties: {
          group_index: 0,
          value: 150,
          center: [110.37306445531925, -7.763547310456208],
          name: "inner",
        },
        geometry: {
          coordinates: [
            [
              [110.358458, -7.761048],
              [110.359775, -7.766934],
              [110.361067, -7.768489],
              [110.366009, -7.777826],
              [110.367841, -7.778932],
              [110.367974, -7.778939],
              [110.376953, -7.774523],
              [110.383649, -7.769544],
              [110.387071, -7.767945],
              [110.387082, -7.767919],
              [110.383509, -7.758643],
              [110.382457, -7.756286],
              [110.373039, -7.749695],
              [110.372394, -7.748937],
              [110.372202, -7.748859],
              [110.368253, -7.748905],
              [110.360261, -7.755119],
              [110.358998, -7.759105],
              [110.358458, -7.761048],
            ],
          ],
          type: "Polygon",
        },
      },
      {
        type: "Feature",
        properties: {
          group_index: 0,
          value: 300,
          center: [110.37306445531925, -7.763547310456208],
          name: "outer",
        },
        geometry: {
          coordinates: [
            [
              [110.340501, -7.746678],
              [110.341258, -7.748806],
              [110.341277, -7.748819],
              [110.343561, -7.748573],
              [110.348078, -7.749304],
              [110.353, -7.756003],
              [110.353117, -7.758348],
              [110.354103, -7.764105],
              [110.353904, -7.767563],
              [110.354281, -7.76994],
              [110.357199, -7.777858],
              [110.356138, -7.782538],
              [110.356133, -7.782576],
              [110.356158, -7.782917],
              [110.358465, -7.789169],
              [110.358507, -7.789195],
              [110.367208, -7.791898],
              [110.3694, -7.791342],
              [110.370042, -7.791178],
              [110.376603, -7.788949],
              [110.376837, -7.78849],
              [110.377084, -7.787395],
              [110.384376, -7.779797],
              [110.386823, -7.779643],
              [110.38716, -7.779556],
              [110.390712, -7.776963],
              [110.39405, -7.770693],
              [110.396416, -7.764533],
              [110.396462, -7.7643],
              [110.396851, -7.761966],
              [110.396888, -7.761722],
              [110.397112, -7.759593],
              [110.396004, -7.757578],
              [110.395933, -7.757549],
              [110.391175, -7.753969],
              [110.391352, -7.74469],
              [110.391456, -7.74451],
              [110.390382, -7.742087],
              [110.390333, -7.74207],
              [110.382548, -7.734621],
              [110.382079, -7.727715],
              [110.381049, -7.725737],
              [110.380802, -7.725521],
              [110.380721, -7.725499],
              [110.378725, -7.726407],
              [110.378649, -7.726603],
              [110.376259, -7.730874],
              [110.364958, -7.727939],
              [110.36474, -7.72723],
              [110.364669, -7.727001],
              [110.362468, -7.726045],
              [110.362352, -7.726083],
              [110.361228, -7.728059],
              [110.355288, -7.737032],
              [110.349829, -7.740159],
              [110.344099, -7.742356],
              [110.342559, -7.743532],
              [110.342056, -7.744127],
              [110.340501, -7.746678],
            ],
          ],
          type: "Polygon",
        },
      },
    ],
    metadata: {
      attribution: "openrouteservice.org | OpenStreetMap contributors",
      service: "isochrones",
      timestamp: 1623658989426,
      query: {
        locations: [[110.37313501406109, -7.763440484516543]],
        range: [300, 150],
      },
      engine: {
        version: "6.5.0",
        build_date: "2021-05-17T12:08:50Z",
        graph_date: "2021-05-31T22:36:37Z",
      },
    },
  };

  export default kosJson;
```

But my problem is 'kosJson' variable still not imported in static/coba/index.html file. The error in console is like this:

1. ReferenceError: kosJson is not defined
2. You are running Vue in development mode.
   Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
3. SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'